# How to use Bounds and RectangleToScreen method with any kind of Form to get screen coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm suffering for quite a long time with getting the real screen coordinates (clientrectangle and bounds) of a general Form instance (can be modal, non-modal, MDI container, MDI child, everything). Looks like the Bounds, and RectangleToScreen method have a completely different behaviour in the mentioned Form scnenarios.

I've tried with checking if the Form is MdiChild or not, or wether it has a visible header or not, but there are so many possiblities that I'm going crazy with it.

I would like a method which give correct results all the time, for every possible kind of Form in every circumstance. Thank you for any help.

PS: I need it for a general algorythm which would place a "Loading" overlay panel above a form.

Comment: Could you please put examples of the exact problems you are having? The characteristics of the form shouldn't matter.

Comment: I got different results when a Form was an MDI child, or the Form had no header. But I'm actually starting to figure it out. Seems like the problem was that if a Form is an MDI child, I have to call the RectangleToClient method on its MDI parent instead of on itself. That way it looks like I get correct results. I will post my final code when it's verified.

Comment: Post your correction or update the question/title to reflect that actually there is no problem with ClientRectangle.